# Buffering in code with subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I've got a job from my boss, to record all broadcast traffic and analyze it. Now, i have to do this in a python script. I have written the script so far so that it reads out the traffic, and works with it. Then, i've got an output. This Output bothers me, because it has sort of an Buffering / Delay in it. Now, i can't find the reason for that. Can anybody help me here?

```
# !/usr/bin/python3.5
import subprocess
import atexit
from datetime import datetime
import signal
import sys
import os


def exit_handler():
    print "\nSkript wurde manuell beendet..."


class Broadcasting_Host:
    def __init__(self, mac="", ips=[]):
        self.mac = mac
        self.broadcast = {}
        print("Broadcasting Host found at: %s" % (mac))

    def broadcasting(self, srcport=0, dstport=0, protokoll="", zeit="", ip="", layer_4_type=""):
        broadcast_key = "%s_%s_%s" % (srcport, dstport, protokoll)
        if ip:
            if ip not in self.broadcast.keys():
                print("User_MAC: %s, has another IP" % (self.mac))
                self.broadcast[ip] = dict()
            # falls dieser broadcast neu ist hinzufuegen
            if broadcast_key not in self.broadcast[ip].keys():
                self.broadcast[ip][broadcast_key] = list()
                print("New broadcast Type detected, for MAC: %s, KEY: %s" % (self.mac, broadcast_key))
        else:
            if "No_IP" not in self.broadcast.keys():
                self.broadcast["No_IP"] = list()
            # broadcast zeit hinzufuegen
        if broadcast_key == "0_0_ARP":
            self.broadcast["No_IP"].append(zeit)
            #print("User: %s, is searching for somebody. KEY: %s" % (self.mac, broadcast_key))
        else:
            self.broadcast[ip][broadcast_key].append(zeit)

        self.drawback

    def drawback(self):
        """gibt die aktuellen broadcast fuer diese object aus"""
        if self.broadcast["ARP"] >= 5:
            print(self.broadcast)
            return self.broadcast

    def cleanup(self):
        pass

    def check_if_correct(self):
        pass


def define_ports(tcp_srcport="", tcp_dstport="", udp_srcport="", udp_dstport=""):
    if tcp_srcport:
        srcport = int(tcp_srcport)
        dstport = int(tcp_dstport)
        layer_type = "TCP"
    elif udp_srcport:
        srcport = int(udp_srcport)
        dstport = int(udp_dstport)
        layer_type = "UDP"
    else:
        srcport, dstport, layer_type = [0, 0, "ARP"]
    return srcport, dstport, layer_type


def split_line(define_ports, line):
    zeit, protokoll, info, mac_source, ip_source, mac_ziel, ip_ziel, tcp_srcport, tcp_dstport, udp_srcport, udp_dstport = line.replace("\n", "").split("\t")
    ms = zeit.split('.')[1].split(" ")[0]
    zeit = datetime.strptime(zeit.replace(ms, ms[:6]), "%b  %d, %Y %H:%M:%S.%f %Z")
    srcport, dstport, layer_4_type = define_ports(tcp_srcport=tcp_srcport, tcp_dstport=tcp_dstport, udp_srcport=udp_srcport, udp_dstport=udp_dstport)
    return zeit, protokoll, info, mac_source, ip_source, mac_ziel, ip_ziel, srcport, dstport, layer_4_type


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Dies ist eine Funktion die das Traceback beim druecken von CTRL + C unterdrueckt.
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, lambda x, y: sys.exit(0))
    # In diesem Programm, benutze ich diese Funktion um beim druecken von CTRL + C noch eine Textausgabe zu bekommen.
    atexit.register(exit_handler)
    # Der Command welcher in einem Subprocess ausgefuehrt wird.
    cmd = "tshark -T fields -e frame.time -e _ws.col.Protocol -e _ws.col.Info -e eth.src -e ip.src -e eth.dst -e ip.dst -e tcp.srcport -e tcp.dstport -e udp.srcport -e udp.dstport -Y \"eth.addr == FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF\""
    # Subprocces mit integriertem command
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, bufsize=0, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    stdout = []
    seltsame_hosts = {}
    while True:
        line = p.stdout.readline()
        #
        #
        if not line:
            # no entries
            continue
        #
        if "Capturing" in line:
            # unnecessary line
            continue
        #
        zeit, protokoll, info, mac_source, ip_source, mac_ziel, ip_ziel, srcport, dstport, layer_4_type = split_line(define_ports, line)
        #
        if mac_source not in seltsame_hosts:
            ips = [ip_source]
            seltsame_hosts[mac_source] = Broadcasting_Host(mac=mac_source, ips=ips)
        #
        seltsame_hosts[mac_source].broadcasting(srcport=srcport, dstport=dstport, protokoll=protokoll, zeit=zeit, ip=ip_source, layer_4_type=layer_4_type)
```

Comment: if underlying process does not flush its output, there's nothing you can do...

Comment: That's quite a bit of code there... you are just interested in the tshark output?

Comment: From [D.2. tshark: Terminal-based Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/AppToolstshark.html) _-l    flush standard output after each packet_   ... that's an "ell" for those with hard to read fonts.

Comment: @tdelaney Thanks for the help. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, you can try to run the command via `stdbuf` to override the default full buffering of output to a pipe to instead use line buffering or no buffering. This will usually work, unless the program manually sets the buffering at startup

On Windows, if underlying process does not flush its output, there's nothing you can do but wait for blocks of text to display instead of smooth line-by-line printouts.

But in that case, as tdelaney [pointed out](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/AppToolstshark.html), there's a platform-independent solution: an option to flush output at each line. So add `-l` to your command and you'll have regular/smoother output

```
cmd = "tshark -l -T fields -e frame.time -e _ws.col.Protocol -e _ws.col.Info -e eth.src -e ip.src -e eth.dst -e ip.dst -e tcp.srcport -e tcp.dstport -e udp.srcport -e udp.dstport -Y \"eth.addr == FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF\""
```

Comment: @eryksun Well, i think i could do so but this answers works perfectely. :D

Comment: @M.Kälin, I was responding to the first sentence of this answer. I'm glad the proposed solution works perfectly for you.

Comment: @eryksun okay, I'll edit. I know that it's a no-go on windows. since it's community wiki, I'm allowed to rip off other people work :)